# How can I do SSH to a specific location when I open new tab/window in iterm2?

Tags: terminal, automation, iterm2

I want to be able to do SSH automatically as soon as I open new tab/window in iterm2.

I have tried creating a new profile in iterm2->preferences->profiles.
Tried using "send text as start" and "command" options.

I have mentioned the "ssh host@server" command in "command" section.
Command runs fine when new tab/window is opened.

But my ssh also requires a password. Can I insert password also into my customised profile so that it is automatically entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't use a password in this situation. 
However you can use SSH keys, which is a way of authenticating without the use of a password. Read [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) how to set these up.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. :)